# SQL Count returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to count the number of paths present in my table.

[image]

I am trying the following query

```
$db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(path) FROM mytable WHERE username='Rbiaali' AND path='C:\MAMP\htdocs\files\Rbiaali\9-5-2019 01 55 AM.zip'")->fetchColumn();
```

Also even if i use the below it is returning the same value: `0`

```
path LIKE 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\files\Rbiaali\9-5-2019 01 55 AM.zip%'
```

As in the table, we can see that there are 6 entries with the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes, because backslash is the escape character in MySQL. `\f` is a form-feed character.

```
$db_con->query("SELECT COUNT(path) FROM mytable WHERE username='Rbiaali' AND path='C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\files\\Rbiaali\\9-5-2019 01 55 AM.zip'")->fetchColumn();
```

If you're getting the path from a variable, use a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(path) FROM mytable WHERE username=:user AND path=:path");
$stmt->execute([":user" => $u, ":path" => $p]);
$stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: if i have the path value as php variable how to do it in php?

Comment: Use a prepared statement with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash `\` is causing the problem.

Run the `$path` variable through `addslashes()` method.

[addslashes() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: this can be a good approach but i will be using prepared statements for counting

Answer (score -2):

try to di this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(path) FROM mytable WHERE username='Rbiaali' AND path='C:\MAMP\htdocs\files\Rbiaali\9-5-2019 01 55 AM.zip'");
$value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
$data = $value->id;
```

Comment: He's using PDO, not mysqli.

Comment: Where does `$value->id` come from? There's no `id` column in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(path) as path FROM mytable WHERE username='Rbiaali' AND path='C:\MAMP\htdocs\files\Rbiaali\9-5-2019 01 55 AM.zip'`
 change query and write
$value->path

Comment: So you're saying that the problem is that he's using PDO, and he need to switch to mysqli to fix it?

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes. You need to escape them twice: once for PHP (because you used a double-quoted string) and again for MySQL.